# Using a command, how can I deal damage to players in a range of five blocks from myself?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for a command that will deal damage to all players in a range of five blocks. Ideally, I'd like for this to be one singular command.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, lars games! With Minecraft command questions, we generally like to see what efforts you've tried so far. Have you tried any commands to do this yet? If so, what are they, and in what way were they unsuccessful?

Comment: i tried commands like /damage @e[distance=5] but it limited only one, and i tried /effect @e[distance=5] but that didnt work either

Answer (score 2):

Here is a command that will execute at a targeted player and damage any entity in a sphere of 5.

```
execute at SemlanBakelsen as @e[distance=..5,name=!SemlanBakelsen] run effect give @s minecraft:instant_damage 5 0 true
```

This command uses my name to run at my location but as any entity within 5 blocks that doesn't have my name.

You can also do the same with a tag:

```
execute at @e[tag=Death] as @e[distance=..5,tag=!Death] run effect give @s minecraft:instant_damage 5 0 true
```

Now it executes the command at all entities with the tag `Death` and damages anyone without it.

Here it is with the `damage` command:

```
execute at @e[tag=Death] as @e[distance=..5,tag=!Death] run damage @s 5
```

There are more ways to target someone like scores, held items, etc.